# read a temp folder file in swift 3

Tags: swift, io

I have the following Swift 3 code that creates a file path string and checks to see if the file exists on the iPad, but it returns false. I see the file in the folder using the IExplorer app, so I must be creating the wrong file path. How do I create the right file path to read the file shown in the screenshot.

The Staff Mobility app in the screenshot is my app where the following code is running.

```
var logPath = FileManager.default.temporaryDirectory.appendingPathComponent("log",
              isDirectory: true).appendingPathComponent("AwpLog4jInfo").appendingPathExtension("log").absoluteString

//This "if" equals false. Why?    
if fileManager.fileExists(asPath: logPath)
```

[image: Screenshot showing the file is on the iPad]

Comment: What is 'absoluteString' for?

Comment: `.absoluteString` is wrong. You have to use `.path`. `let logPath = FileManager.default.temporaryDirectory.appendingPathComponent("log",
              isDirectory: true).appendingPathComponent("AwpLog4jInfo").appendingPathExtension("log").path`

Comment: Changing it to use .path worked. Thanks